# como trabajar actualizar varios select con ajax

Tags: ajax, select

estoy cargando el contenido de varios select con ajax, todo me sale bien cuando ejecuto uno por uno, pero al momento de anidarlos ejecuta el ajax pero no coge el valor refrescado, es decir tengo tres select y deseo que al ejecutar el ajax del primer select actualice al segundo select y al actualizarse este ejecute un segundo ajax y este actualice el tercer select, dejo mi codigo que esta casi ok porque no coge el valor mostrado:

```
<select name="tipdoc" id="tipdoc" onchange="traerccp(this.value);">
<option value="FAC">FACTURA</option>
<option value="BOL">BOLETA</option>
</select>

<select name="concepto" id="concepto" onchange="traerser(this.value);">
<option value="VTA">VENTA</option>
</select>

<select name="serie" id="serie">
<option value="1">1</option>
</select>
```

esos son los tres select los cuales estan anidados y cada uno tiene una funcion con ajax que actualiza a la otra, muestro el codigo en js:

```
//llamo a los conceptos según el tipo de documento escogido
function traerccp(tido){
        var empr = $("#empresa").val();
        var parametros = {
                            "empr" : empr,
                            "tido" : tido};
        $.ajax({
            data:  parametros,
            url:   '?accion=traerconcepto',
            type:  'post',
            dataType: "html",
            success:  function (response) 
            {
                  $("#concepto").html(response);
            }
        });
// hasta aquí todo bien, hasta cambia los valores en select concepto, pero en
// la siguiente linea de código el valor de concepto no cambio, es decir se
// quedo con el valor "VTA" y al llamar la funcion de traer las series
// tambien con ajax el resultado es erroneo
        traerdoc($("#concepto").val());}

    function traerser(ccep){
        var empr = $("#empresa").val();
        var tido = $("#tipdoc").val();
        var parametros = {
                            "tido" : tido,
                            "ccep" : ccep,
                            "empr" : empr};
        $.ajax({
            data:  parametros,
            url:   '?accion=traerserie',
            type:  'post',
            dataType: "html",
            success:  function (response) 
            {
                  $("#serie").html(response);
            }
        });}
```

espero sus comentarios gracias.

Comment: Intenta poner esta linea: `traerdoc($("#concepto").val());` dentro del `success` de la llamada Ajax.

Comment: funciono perfect (Y)

Answer (score 1):

Sugiero:

```
function traerccp(tido){
    var empr = $("#empresa").val();
    var parametros = {
        "empr" : empr,
        "tido" : tido
    };
    $.ajax({
        data:  parametros,
        url:   '?URL_que_retornara_los_datos',
        type:  'post',
        dataType: "html",
        success:  function (response){
              $("#concepto").append(response);
        }
    });
}
```

De manera similar para las otras funciones.
O alternativamente:

```
dataType: "json",
success:  function (response){
    $("#concepto").append("<option>"+response.concepto+"</option>");
}
```

Comment: funciono con llamar la función dentro del `success`, gracias.

Answer (score 0):

intenta con esto:

```
$( document ).on( "change", "#tipdoc", function() {
   // lo que esta dentro de la function traerccp(tido){
}

$( document ).on( "change", "#concepto", function() {
   // lo que esta dentro de la traerser(ccep){
}
```

con esto eliminas los onchange del html
al hacer la primera llamada a ajax el elemento se vuelve dinamico
aparecio luego de que el html estuviese cargado!

https://codepen.io/NickEngeldinger/pen/qZXXMg

Comment: ya funciono gracias :)